# jackson Pascal Case and @JsonProperty on getter

Tags: java, json, jackson

i create a mapper with

```
new ObjectMApper()
        .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE)
        .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
```

and serialization works perfectly on fields (no getters and setters). field `currentStatus` is serialized to `"currentStatus"` (first letter uppercase). but i have also one getter (without a field and setter) which must be camelCase. so i do:

```
@JsonProperty("abcDef")
public String getZxy() {...
```

but it is serialized to `"AbcDef"` instead of `"abcDef"`. it looks like naming strategy still triggers and change the first letter. i use jackson-databind 2.3.2;

how can i map this getter with first letter lowercase?

---

EDIT:
ugly code, but shows the problem. this test should pass but it fails

```
import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;

public class JsonFailureTest {

    @Test
    public void should_serialize_first_letter_lowercase() throws Exception {

        String json = new ObjectMapper()
                            .setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.PASCAL_CASE_TO_CAMEL_CASE)
                            .writeValueAsString(

        new Object(){

            @JsonProperty("fooBar")
            public String whatever() {return "";}

        });

        assertThat(json).contains("fooBar");
    }
}
```

Comment: FWIW, this is a real bug, and is reported as https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a workaround using a custom "annotation-aware" strategy:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.cfg.MapperConfig;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedMethod;

public class Foo {
    public static void main(final String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        final SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
        someObject.setZxy("foobar");

        final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy.PascalCaseStrategy() {
            @Override
            public String nameForGetterMethod(final MapperConfig<?> config, final AnnotatedMethod method, final String defaultName) {
                final JsonProperty annotation = method.getAnnotation(JsonProperty.class);
                if (annotation != null) {
                    return annotation.value();
                }
                return super.nameForGetterMethod(config, method, defaultName);
            }
        });
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);

        System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObject));
    }

    private static class SomeObject {

        private String zxy;

        @JsonProperty("abcDef")
        public String getZxy() {
            return this.zxy;
        }

        public void setZxy(final String zxy) {
            this.zxy = zxy;
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"abcDef":"foobar"}
```